# How can I combine HTTP requests in JMeter to get a total response time

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I have a series of requests that I would like to make that basically render a page.   I would like to be able to show the total time that those requests make as single line the results summary, currently they show as separate lines.

- My page

  - Get HTML
  - Ajax call 1
  - Ajax call 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transaction controller is what you are looking for. http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller